# UploadStringAsync CallBack Return Type

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, return-type, uploadstring

I have a web service where I Post to a URL Asynchronously

```
public Response uploadXMLData(string destinationUrl, string requestXml,Request req)
{
    try
    {
        Response resp=new Response();
        System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(destinationUrl);
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {

            client.UploadStringCompleted
       += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(UploadStringCallback); 

            client.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST",requestXml,req);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {}

    return resp;
}

public void UploadStringCallback(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Response resp=new Response();
    Request req = new Request();
    try 
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            object objException = e.Error.GetBaseException();

            Type _type = typeof(WebException);
            if (_type != null)
            {
                WebException objErr = (WebException)e.Error.GetBaseException();
                WebResponse rsp = objErr.Response;
                using (Stream respStream = rsp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                   req= (Request)e.UserState;
                   resp=Utilities.ParseWithoutSoapEnv(respStream);

                }

            }
            else
            {
                Exception objErr = (Exception)e.Error.GetBaseException();
                throw objErr;
            }
        }
        else
        { 
        //Parse e.Result
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {}
}
```

The Function Called `Utilities.ParseWithoutSoapEnv(respStream);` returns Type `Response`

what I want to do is get the Response from that function, and make it the return value for `uploadXMLData`

But I can't change the return type of a CallBack Function, so I have no idea what to do.

When someone calls my webservice function, they expect it to return a type of `Response`, and the `Response` class I need is being received to the CallBack function..

Hope I made my issue clear

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: events cannot return data. You might use your `Response` object as a global variable so that you have access to it inside your callback method.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh and how do I return it from the main WebMethod in the webservice?

Comment: Do you only get `Response` back when an exception occurs? Or is that a general return type from the web call?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It is a general type, I parse e.Result to the Response class as well

Comment: You'll return from your main method the same way as it is. If you're able to set desired result to your global response  object when the callback is called, the same would be returned from the main.

Comment: And `Utilities.ParseWithoutSoapEnv` only accepts a stream?

Comment: BTW, which .NET version are you using?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh how can I return a Response Class from the function uploadXMLData  if it is  a global variable?

Comment: you'll return the global variable after all you had to do is complete.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It accepts only Stream. I can show you the function if its relevant. but what I care about is for the UploadXmlData to return Response class. Im using .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Things get a little easier if you use the [Task Asynchronous Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) and `HttpClient`. You'll need to modify your method to return a `Task<Response>`:

```
public async Task<Response> UploadXmlDataAsync(
                 string destinationUrl, 
                 string requestXml,
                 Request req)
{
    try
    {
        Response resp=new Response();
        System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(destinationUrl);

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(Uri, new StringContent(requestxml))
                               .ConfigureAwait(false);
        var responeStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Utilities.ParseWithoutSoapEnv(responseStream);
    }
}
```

And when you call it higher up the call-stack, you'll need to `await` that too:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    var parsedResponse = await UploadXmlDataAsync(url, xml, request);
    // Do something with response.
}
```

If you want a synchronous alternative, you can also do:

```
public Response UploadXmlData(string destinationUrl, string requestXml,Request req)
{
    Response resp=new Response();
    System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(destinationUrl);
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        var response = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", requestXml, req);
        using (var responseStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response))
        {
            return Utilities.ParseWithoutSoapEnv(responseStream);
        }
    }
}
```